# Yii Framework 2.0 $model->validate always returns true

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I'm new to the yii2 framework.I cant understand where i did the mistake.Below is my code.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['oldpassword', 'newpassword','reenternewpassword'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['reenternewpassword', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'newpassword'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['oldpassword', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

public function validatePassword()
    {

        $this->password_hash= User::findOne(['username'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->username,'status'=> User::STATUS_ACTIVE])->password_hash;
        if(is_null($this->oldpassword))
            return false;
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->oldpassword, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function actionChangepwd()
{
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            if($model->validate()){
             echo 'pwd correct';
            }
            else
            {
             echo 'pwd incorrect';
            }
        }
}
```

Here validatePassword is returning false but model validate function is returning true.How?Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify function `validatePassword` to:

```
public function validatePassword($attribute)
        {

            $this->password_hash= User::findOne([
                 'username' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
                 'status'=> User::STATUS_ACTIVE
                ])->password_hash;
            if(is_null($this->oldpassword)) {
                    $this->addError($attribute, \Yii::t('app', 'Wrong message');
            }
            if(!Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->oldpassword, $this->password_hash)) {
                    $this->addError($attribute, \Yii::t('app', 'Wrong message');
            } 
        }
```

Btw, you don't check if User exists, which can throw Exception in this validator.

Comment: Remember to check if user is found!

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you do this, as validatePassword() is the method which checks the values to be true or false,

```
public function actionChangepwd()
{
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            if($model->validatePassword()){
             echo 'pwd correct';
            }
            else
            {
             echo 'pwd incorrect';
            }
        }
}
```